# Making REST calls only available to local applications?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-piston

Suppose I have a url like:

http://example.com/get-users

which returns a JSON object of all users. But, I don't want anyone (or any bots) to be able to go to this url to fetch this information. I want it to only respond to calls from other local modules in the same website.

How would I go about implementing someting like this?

Comment: You are making HTTP requests between code modules that are on the same web site?  Are they in the same process?  Does HTTP not seem like overkill for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the REMOTE_ADDR against a white list of approved IPs. If it's not in that list, simply return nothing, close the socket, or return an HTTP error.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Spring? Have considered adding a filter bean inside your context to only allow HTTP requests from your site?

Comment: hey! no, i'm actually doing this in django(python) and not in java.